# Formulas across Excel files

Tags: excel-formula

I have two Excel 2010 files created by ex-employee. Need File 2 to quantify when data in column M of file 1 for a particular manager has a status of "Open". The code I was using is.

```
COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&"[file1.xlsx]"&Q3&"'!M2:M1500"),"=Open")
```

I think I am missing the tab name after the file but when I inserted it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an example of your data it is hard to tell what you want exactly.

You will want to use `COUNTIFS` since you have multiple criteria.

I added a list of Manager Names to my new sheet and referenced the list within the `COUNTIFS`:

[image]

Assuming the status is in `Column M` of the other sheet and the Manager Name is in `Column N` of the other sheet and your list of Manager Names is in `Column A` of your new sheet, you can use this formula to count "Open" statuses by Manager:

```
   =COUNTIFS([file1.xlsx]Sheet1!$N:$N,A1,[file1.xlsx]Sheet1!$M:$M,"Open")
```

[image: image2]